# Is $n^2+1$ always a product of Pythagorean primes?

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that every positive integer $1$ bigger than a square is a Pythagorean prime (one which is the sum of 2 squares, and I'm including $2 = 1^2+1^2$) or a product of same?

If so, is there an elementary proof?

Comment: Is your question, can $n^2+1$ be represented as the sum of two squares?

Answer (score 1):

- Every prime number that divided by $4$ gives $1$ as rest is the sum of two squares.
- If a prime number divides $n^2+1$ is of the type above.

[First fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

[Second fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=n^2+1=(n+i)(n-i)$. Since the ring $R$ of Gaussian integers is a Unique factorization domain, you can write $n+i$ as the unique product of elements $z_1, \ldots, z_k$ of $R$. But then $n-i = \overline{z_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\overline{z_k}$, and $N=|z_1|^2\cdot\ldots\cdot|z_k|^2$ is a factorization of $N$ into Pythagorean primes.